# Add new element to an array of objects and show in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of objects that is going to be filled with new objects from filling a `form` and calling `addEventListener` on `submit`.

I tried to `push` the new object inside the `event listener` but looks that it's only working inside the scope of the function.
Is there another way to add this new object into the array?

Here is my code:

```js
const empleados = [{
    nombre: "Kevin",
    apellido: "Malone",
    edad: 30,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Pam",
    apellido: "Beesley",
    edad: 69,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Jim",
    apellido: "Halpert",
    edad: 40,
  },
];
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const table = document.querySelector(".table");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let nuevoEmpleado = {
    nombre: form.name.value,
    apellido: form.lastname.value,
    edad: form.age.value,
  };
  empleados.push(nuevoEmpleado);
  form.reset();
});
empleados.forEach((chabon) => {
  let html = `<div class="table">
<div class="empleado"><span class="name">Nombre: ${chabon.nombre}</span> <span class="apellido">Apellido: ${chabon.apellido}</span> <span class="edad">Edad: ${chabon.edad}</span></div>
</div>`;
  table.innerHTML += html;
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="">
    <span>Nombre</span><input type="text" class="name" name="name">
    <span>Apellido</span><input type="text" class="lastname" name="lastname">
    <span>Edad</span><input type="text" class="age" name="age">
    <button>Agregar</button>
  </form>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="empleado"><span class="name"></span><span class="edad"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `empleados.push(nuevoEmpleado);` before you create the object?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to delete that part of the code, now its ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your current function IS pushing the new object (`nuevoEmpleado`) to the array, you are only not seeing it because you are not updating the DOM/HTML or not even logging the array afte pushing new objects.

So, create a function that prints the `empleados` to your table. Call this function on initialization and every time that a new `empleado` is added.

See below code, and the comments inside it

```js
const empleados = [{
    nombre: "Kevin",
    apellido: "Malone",
    edad: 30,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Pam",
    apellido: "Beesley",
    edad: 69,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Jim",
    apellido: "Halpert",
    edad: 40,
  },
];

const form = document.querySelector("form");
const table = document.querySelector(".table");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let nuevoEmpleado = {
    nombre: form.name.value,
    apellido: form.lastname.value,
    edad: form.age.value,
  };

  empleados.push(nuevoEmpleado);

  form.reset();
  //"re-print" the empleados, calling the function that does it
  printEmpleados();
});

//HERE: new function that "prints" the empleados to the table
printEmpleados = function() {
  //clear the table HTML before fill it again
  table.innerHTML = "";
  empleados.forEach((chabon) => {
    let html = `<div class="table">
<div class="empleado"><span class="name">Nombre: ${chabon.nombre}</span> <span class="apellido">Apellido: ${chabon.apellido}</span> <span class="edad">Edad: ${chabon.edad}</span></div>
</div>`;
    table.innerHTML += html;
  });
}

//call at startup to start showing 
printEmpleados();
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="">
    <span>Nombre</span><input type="text" class="name" name="name">
    <span>Apellido</span><input type="text" class="lastname" name="lastname">
    <span>Edad</span><input type="text" class="age" name="age">
    <button>Agregar</button>
  </form>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="empleado"><span class="name"></span><span class="edad"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not that there is no update in the array, because it clearly works.

Just add `console.log(empleados);` right after `empleados.push(nuevoEmpleado);`

Your problem is that you do not see any update in your HTML. And that's because you don't update the table after that.